# Prevent conversion from derived class to 3rd-party base class while retaining public inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-conversion, c++20, implicit-conversion

As the title says, I'd like to prevent implicit conversions from a derived class to its base class while retaining public inheritance. **I do not have access to the base class implementation.** Example:

```
// I cannot edit anything in the `thirdparty` namespace
namespace thirdparty {
    struct base { void f(); };
}

// I do not know what `T` is in advance
template <typename T>
struct derived : T { };

int main()
{
    derived<thirdparty::base> d;
    d.f(); // I want 'f' to be exposed via public inheritance

    thirdparty::base b = d; // I want this to be a compiler error
}
```

I tried deleting conversion operators as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct derived : T { 
    operator const T&() const& = delete;
    operator T&() & = delete;
    operator T&&() && = delete;
};
```

However, that had no effect. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Since `derived` publicly derives from `base` then it is a `base` and a `base` can copy itself.

Comment: If you're okay with also losing `thirdparty::base& b = d;` you could write an explicit specialization for `derived<thirdparty::base>` that contains a data member of type `thirdparty::base` and provides its own `f()` that forwards to the data member. Or derive privately and re-public `f()` with `using thirdparty::base::f;` in the public part of `derived`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I see. Any way I can prevent that from `derived` without touching `base`?

Comment: @PeteBecker: I would like to not have to manually specify `f` or specialize `derived` anywhere, it should be as ergonomic as possible and `derived<T>` should expose the same API as `T` without manually re-implementing it.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo If you could live with some extra work for each of the classes in `thirdparty` that you want to impose this restriction upon, you could make some specializations. Not pretty, but once done a user would probably see it as ergonomic. Perhaps. You'd only have to make the `destroyer` specialization once per class in `thirdparty` so, it may even be possible to generate the specializations [An idea](https://godbolt.org/z/Wf5sh4191)

Comment: _"...Conversion function to its own (possibly cv-qualified) class (or to a reference to it), to the base of its own class (or to a reference to it), and to the type void __can be defined, but can not be executed as part of the conversion sequence__, except, in some cases, through virtual dispatch:..."_ [user-defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) - live see warnings - https://godbolt.org/z/E18z1h6sc

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I am unaware of any mechanism to do that.  The built in conversion from a derived class to a public base class happen automagically from the compiler and no conversion operator will be called in its place.

Comment: You have an XY-problem. Instead of working in the solution domain, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? (I.e., why is `protected` inheritance out of question)

Comment: *"`thirdparty::base b = d; // I want this to be a compiler error`"* -- how do you feel about the same end result coming from more steps, as in `thirdparty::base& ref = d; thirdparty::base b = ref;`? The first statement is allowed by -- and from one perspective is the reason for -- the public inheritance you desire, and the validity of the second statement depends only on the definition of `base`.

Comment: We need `-fno-object-slicing` (I'm only half joking)

Comment: @PaulSanders would you like to elaborate on joking part? And serious part if you have time. In case I got it wrong.

Comment: @lorro: I am trying to find a new technique to easily implement strong typedefs with minimal manual intervention required by the user.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Who is the user in this scenario? With the `destroyer` layer I proposed, one integrator would write the specializations (or generate them). The end users of your `derived` class(es) wouldn't be aware I think.

Comment: @LouisGo `thirdparty::base b = d` 'slices' `d`, which is frequently a mistake.  I think there are situations where it would be nice to have the compiler at least warn you, that's all I meant.

Comment: Another alternative to inheritance: `template <typename T> struct derived { T* operator->() { return &i; } T i{}; };` and let users use `d->f();`